Can diffusion create a vacuum?
As I understand it, helium diffuses at appreciable rates even through materials like glass or metal that are essentially impermeable to atmospheric gases.
So if I have a metal canister filled with helium at atmospheric pressure, the helium will diffuse into the walls of the canister and from there into the outside atmosphere.
That implies the pressure inside the container will fall to zero, since the partial pressure of helium outside the container basically remains at zero, and atmospheric gases can’t diffuse in the other direction.  So after enough years, I’ll have a vacuum that I could use to do work.
That sounds wrong but I’m not clear why. Is this what would actually happen, and if so, where is the work “coming from”?

Why can atmospheric gases not diffuse into the container?

Diffusion doesn't create a vacuum this way. You have supplied a helium vacuum outside of the container.

The concentration of He in the atmosphere is 5.2 ppm,

I have actually done this very experiment, starting with a sealed, permeable vessel (Teflon) filled with helium at 1 atm surrounded by air at 1 atm.  What happens is over several days the pressure falls to a low of about 0.85 to 0.9 atm, and then slowly rises back to 1 atm.
The explanation is that the vessel also permeable to air/nitrogen, but at a much lower rate. At the beginning, the helium escapes at a rate greater than the air seeps in, so the total pressure inside decreases. As time goes on (and assisted by the increasing inward pressure differential, and the helium escape rate becoming less), the air permeation replenishes the gas inside.
So, in your example the only way to truly get a vacuum inside the vessel at the end is to start with a vacuum on the outside.  But, supposing you chose a hypothetical material that was permeable to helium, but with vanishingly low permeability to the outside medium (maybe water or oil), you could in theory reach an arbitrarily low pressure on the inside, which would remain indefinitely.
The driving force for this is the outward gradient in the partial pressure of helium, which can end up producing an opposite gradient in total pressure.  You could also frame the helium gradient as a gradient in chemical potential, which as it evens out drives movement in total system pressure "uphill."
This idea of one type of gradient driving another type uphill against a gradient is how virtually every mechanism or cycle works.  A battery uses chemical potential (which is trying to equalize within the battery) to drive electrical energy "uphill," separating charges which can then be used to do work.  Any thermodynamic heat engine uses heat flow down a thermal gradient to drive mechanical work uphill against a mechanical gradient (gravity or otherwise).  It is nothing but energy conversion from one form to another.  Your helium example is converting chemical or entropic energy (mixing of uneven concentrations) into mechanical energy (pressure difference).

That seems perfectly reasonable to me! The pressure inside the container will indeed drop to zero after a while.
If you compare the chemical potential of helium inside and outside the container, you'll see that helium diffuses from the high-chemical-potential region (inside) to low-chemical-potential region (outside), similar to how a ball rolls downhill.
The work originates from the initial effort required to isolate the high-purity helium gas (a low-entropy state compared to the outside air, which is a mixture of nitrogen, oxygen, etc.) and filling it into the canister. This entropic effect eventually results in the "work" that can be done by the pressure difference.
Note, however, that the work is only done if the container is compressed by the vacuum ($W = P\Delta V = 0$ if $\Delta V = 0$). In other words, if the metal canister is very strong and does not collapse, then no work is done by diffusion.

It depends entirely on whether the canister allows heat flow across its walls, or is adiabatic.  Temperature is average energy, regardless of quantity of particles.  You can start with 1 mole of helium at 20°C and end up with 20 atoms of helium at 20°C, although at low enough particle densities, the concept of temperature begins to break down.

I think my previous comment ended up posted in the wrong place. What I responded to is not something in your answer


So after enough years, I’ll have a vacuum that I could use to do work.

Yes, if the container is permeable only to helium, then after a long time, the state will be very low pressure helium inside, much lower than the atmospheric pressure.

That sounds wrong but I’m not clear why. Is this what would actually happen, and if so, where is the work “coming from”?

It is not wrong, only non-intuitive, because it is not common to have such container and observe the pressure decrease. Similar phenomenon can be observed, perhaps more easily, in liquids. Imagine the closed container contains pure water, and the outside is salty water, and one wall of the container is made of a semipermeable membrane, allowing only water to go through the membrane, but not salt. In time, net effect of water migration will be that the amount of water inside will decrease, and pressure inside will drop.
Back to your question, the work that can be extracted comes from energy in the atmosphere. It has higher pressure and energy per unit volume than the gas inside. This imbalance of pressure allows the energy to be released. The imbalance was created spontaneously from the initial imbalance of helium concentrations.
